# Request::create is not working in EventSubscriber service class

Tags: 8

Drupal 8 doesn't allows changing the current page in hook_init as we could do it in drupal 7 using following way :

```
$_GET['q'] = '/my-url';
```

But according to [documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/1635626) we can do it using following way :

```
$request = \Drupal::service('request_stack');
$current_request = $request->getCurrentRequest();
Request::create('/my-url', 'GET', $current_request->query->all(), $current_request->cookies->all(), array(), $current_request->server->all());
```

But it still doesn't work.

Note: I have successfully converted the `hook_init` to `EventSubscriber` and other code is working fine.

Comment: Also consider using or looking at how Redirect is doing it: https://github.com/md-systems/redirect

Comment: Thanks @Berdir I want to load the page dynamically in EventSubscriber class. Basically I am porting front page module.

Comment: @IvanJaros Hope this small information in above comment would clarify more about my question.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to assign the value returned from `Request::create()` to a variable, and the rest of the code. The code shown in that documentation page, merged with the code shown in one of its comments is the following.

```php
$request = \Drupal::service('request_stack');
$current_request = $request->getCurrentRequest();
$sub_request = Request::create('/my-url', 'GET', $current_request->query->all(), $current_request->cookies->all(), array(), $current_request->server->all());
return Drupal::service('http_kernel')->handle($subrequest, HttpKernelInterface::SUB_REQUEST);
```

Since you want to write code to redirect users to a different page, the equivalent of what you would write in Drupal 7 `hook_init()`, check also [hook_init() removed](https://www.drupal.org/node/2013014); it contains example code for that case.

```php
namespace Drupal\mymodule\EventSubscriber;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;

class MymoduleSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface {
  public function checkForRedirection(GetResponseEvent $event) {
    if ($event->getRequest()->query->get('redirect-me')) {
      $event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse('http://example.com/'));
    }
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  static function getSubscribedEvents() {
    $events[KernelEvents::REQUEST][] = array('checkForRedirection');
    return $events;
  }
}
```

See also the [`LocalRedirectResponse`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Routing!LocalRedirectResponse.php/class/LocalRedirectResponse/8) class.

The event subscriber for the example is described with the following, in mymodule.services.yaml.

```yaml
services:
  mymodule_event_subscriber:
    class: Drupal\mymodule\EventSubscriber\MymoduleSubscriber
    tags:
      - {name: event_subscriber}
```